# Spark streaming: batch interval vs window

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have spark streaming application which consumes kafka messages. And I want to process all messages coming last 10 minutes together.
Looks like there are two approaches to do job done:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Minutes(10))
val dstream = ....
```

and

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Seconds(1))
val dstream = ....
dstream.window(Minutes(10), Minutes(10))
```

and I just want to clarify is there any performance differences between them

Comment: You can do a quick benchmark and find out!!! But, as "val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Minutes(10))" dose processing once in 10 min, this will be best in terms of processing. The window version will create a job to get latest information from kafka every 1 sec and aggregate every 10 min!!!

Comment: `batchDuration` in `StreamingContext` defines the size of the microbatch. `window()` depends on your application